# Python: Converting ANSI color codes to HTML

Tags: python, html, colors, ansi-escape

I have a program that reads Minecraft console output, and puts it in a Qt text edit field (irrelevant). However, Minecraft consoles use ANSI color codes (`[0;32;1m`) to output colors, and I'd like them in HTML format (since Qt text edit fields read that).

I've researched a bit and found a bunch of solutions that require style sheets, which is not what I want. What I want is a simple `<span style="color: green"></span>` or similar, inline.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansi2html) can help?

Comment: @TimPeters I checked that one, but that does the stylesheet thing that I don't want with a bunch of classes defined.

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

COLOR_DICT = {
    '31': [(255, 0, 0), (128, 0, 0)],
    '32': [(0, 255, 0), (0, 128, 0)],
    '33': [(255, 255, 0), (128, 128, 0)],
    '34': [(0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 128)],
    '35': [(255, 0, 255), (128, 0, 128)],
    '36': [(0, 255, 255), (0, 128, 128)],
}

COLOR_REGEX = re.compile(r'\[(?P<arg_1>\d+)(;(?P<arg_2>\d+)(;(?P<arg_3>\d+))?)?m')

BOLD_TEMPLATE = '<span style="color: rgb{}; font-weight: bolder">'
LIGHT_TEMPLATE = '<span style="color: rgb{}">'


def ansi_to_html(text):
    text = text.replace('[m', '</span>')

    def single_sub(match):
        argsdict = match.groupdict()
        if argsdict['arg_3'] is None:
            if argsdict['arg_2'] is None:
                color, bold = argsdict['arg_1'], 0
            else:
                color, bold = argsdict['arg_1'], int(argsdict['arg_2'])
        else:
            color, bold = argsdict['arg_2'], int(argsdict['arg_3'])

        if bold:
            return BOLD_TEMPLATE.format(COLOR_DICT[color][1])
        return LIGHT_TEMPLATE.format(COLOR_DICT[color][0])

    return COLOR_REGEX.sub(single_sub, text)

print ansi_to_html('[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] [0;31;1mUsage: /kick [reason ...][m')
print ansi_to_html('[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] [31;0mUsage: /kick [reason ...][m')
print ansi_to_html('[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] [31mUsage: /kick [reason ...][m')

[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] <span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 0); font-weight: bolder">Usage: /kick [reason ...]</span>
[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0)">Usage: /kick [reason ...]</span>
[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0)">Usage: /kick [reason ...]</span>
```

Comment: What does the "ansi_code" and "text" parameters do? Which one do I put the text in? What is the other one used for?

Comment: `ansi_code` is the ansi color code which you want the `text` to have in `<span>` element.

Comment: So... if I have a text string like this: `[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] [0;31;1mUsage: /kick [reason ...][m` How would I convert that to HTML? Sorry if I seem stupid, I probably am :)

Comment: You would convert it like so: `'[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] ' + ansi_to_html('[0;31;1m', 'Usage: /kick [reason...]')`. Notice lack of `[m` at the end of second parameter. And the result would be `'[06-10-13 21:28:23] [INFO] <span style="color: rgb(128, 0, 0); font-weight: bolder">Usage: /kick [reason ...]</span>'`

Comment: Thing is, the text to convert isn't in the source code, it's dynamically retrieved from Apache Thrift, so I can't really do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38693/discussion-between-kroolik-and-user1438098)

Comment: Very useful proposition ; although for example ffmpeg's output switches the 'color' and 'bold' parameters. And `COLOR_DICT` is lacking many keycodes. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rene-d/9e584a7dd2935d0f461904b9f2950007#file-colors-py) for more keycodes.